# Can Amazon Lex detect DTMF tones?

Tags: amazon-lex

Is it possible to use Amazon Lex to identify DTMF tones?

I have built an Amazon Connect contact flow that enables users to pay bills from their phone.  I have it working as a DTMF application and separately as a speech application using Amazon Lex to gather the spoken credit card information.

I'd like callers to be able to speak or use button presses to enter sensitive information such as credit card because not everyone will want to speak their credit card information if calling from a public area.  Can Lex understand DTMF?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AWS Connect + Lex will interpret the DTMF tones.

Some data types such as the `AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER` can handle DTMF input automatically. If you use a custom slot type for numerical input, you may need to create a *Lambda initialization and validation* function to help you process the `inputTranscript` field into your desired Lex slot.